# Parsing XML containing two namespaces in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xml-parsing

I have an xml which is returned from wcf and I have to deserialize it to object. Unfortunately I can't use the wcf data contract, because my company is in a process of retiring WCFs, so this solution is temporary. I tried to do it as my other deserializations, but it does not work, I think it is because of the double name space in `Result`.

```xml
<ServiceResponse xmlns="http://www.julianuslemurrex.com/MyWcfService/2023/9/19">
    <ServiceResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2023/9/MyWcfService.Model.DataTransfer" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:IsEmployee i:nil="true"/>
        <a:IsContractor i:nil="true"/>
        <a:EmployeeReference>EMEM001F1</a:EmployeeReference>
    </ServiceResult>
</ServiceResponse>
```

I created two classes:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName="ServiceResponse")]
public class EmployeeDtoRoot
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ServiceResult")]
    public EmployeeDto Root { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ServiceResult")]
public class EmployeeDto
{
    [XmlElement("IsEmployee")]
    public bool IsEmployee { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsContractor")]
    public bool IsContractor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EmployeeReference")]
    public string EmployeeReference { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializaation part of the code:

```cs
using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlToDeserialize))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeDtoRoot));
    
    xtr.Namespaces = false;
    xtr.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    var root = (EmployeeDtoRoot)serializer.Deserialize(xtr);
    var r = root;
}
```

The two classes are connected in correct relation, but values in `EmployeeDto` are empty. The solution above should ignore namespaces, but the xml is not parsed anyway.

How I can parse this? The `EmployeeDtoRoot` should not even be required, I just need the three elements from the xml: `IsEmployee`, `IsContractor` and `Employeereference`.

Comment: Are those classes generated from a wsdl? To me it looks weird that both classes are decorated as `XmlRoot`, and what is the content of `xmlToDeserialize`?

Comment: Class has to be marked as XmlRoot. If is skip the `EmployeeDtoRoot` there is a error when parsing xml because of the node `ServiceResponse`

Comment: Sometimes you can pinpoint issues with deserialization by serializing a dummy object and comparing the result with what you're trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

IsEmployee and IsContractor are both null in the XML but in your class definition they are not nullable.

```
    <a:IsEmployee i:nil="true"/>
    <a:IsContractor i:nil="true"/>
```

So EmployeeDto should look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("ServiceResult")]
public class EmployeeDto
{
    [XmlElement("IsEmployee")]
    public bool? IsEmployee { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsContractor")]
    public bool? IsContractor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EmployeeReference")]
    public string EmployeeReference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have made it nullable, but it still does not work.